# How to not run a job when pull request is closed without merge

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow with 2 jobs, One job should run Terraform Plan when a pull request is created without a label and the other job should run Terraform Apply when a pull request is merged and does not have a label. currently my workflow is running on both occasions. The issue I'm having is that Terraform Plan is also running when the pull request is closed without merge. I only want Terraform Plan to run when a pull request is created without a label.
Below is a snippet of the triggers if I am missing something

```
name: Plan and merge to Main
on:
  pull_request: 
    types: [ labeled, closed, opened ]

jobs:
  Plan:
    name: "Terraform Plan"'
    if: github.base_ref == 'main' && join(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, '') == ''

Apply:
    name: "Run Terraform Apply"
    if: github.base_ref == 'main' && github.event.pull_request.merged == true && join(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name, '') == ''
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s no way to specify that a workflow should be triggered when a pull request is merged. However, because a merged pull request always results in a push, you can use the push event to accomplish your goal.

For example, let’s say that you want to run a workflow whenever a pull request is merged to your main branch. You can do something like this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

also if you want to prevent push directly to main it's part of github pro plan.

Comment: @ marOne i was able to trigger my workflow when a pull request is merged with this condition "github.event.pull_request.merged == true" . What i want is to not trigger my workflow when a pull request is closed without merge

Comment: not merged == not pushed and also closed & not merged == not pushed